# Submitting Form Data to Cloud Firestore using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, forms, google-cloud-firestore, form-submit

Good evening Firebase community! I hope you are having a blessed day! I am building a website for a nonprofit organization and am hoping to gain some help. I am using Firebase hosting to serve a page that has a form in it, and want to use JavaScript to submit the form data to Firestore. When I click the "submit" button, the browser console shows that it captured the user's input, but it is not sending it to Firestore Database. Could someone please point me on the right path? it would be greatly appreciated. The following is what I have so far:

**`firebase.js`**

```
import {
    initializeApp
} from "firebase/app";
import {
    getAnalytics
} from "firebase/analytics";
import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    getDocs
} from "firebase/firestore";


// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries


// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {

    apiKey: "***********",

    authDomain: "***********",

    projectId: "***********",

    storageBucket: "***********",

    messagingSenderId: "***********",

    appId: "***********",

    measurementId: "***********"

};


// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);


const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

**`partnerScripts.js`**

```
import {
    collection,
    addDoc
} from "firebase/firestore";

//Get Form Values
const prefix = document.getElementById('prefixes').value
const firstName = document.getElementById('givenName').value
const lastName = document.getElementById('surName').value
const title = document.getElementById('title').value
const organization = document.getElementById('organization').value
const website = document.getElementById('website').value
const email = document.getElementById('email').value
const phone = document.getElementById('areaCode').value + '-' + document.getElementById('lead3') + '-' + document.getElementById('last4')
const interests = `${document.getElementById('selectAll').value}\n${document.getElementById('bolPantry').value}\n${document.getElementById('FeedMySheep').value}\n${document.getElementById('GiftedShop').value}\n${document.getElementById('GoodNews').value}\n${document.getElementById('KingdomsFlock').value}\n${document.getElementById('OutdooBazaar').value}`

const description = document.getElementById('description')

const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit')

submitButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "partnerRequests"), {
        prefix: prefix,
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        Title: title,
        Organization: organization,
        Website: website,
        Email: email,
        PhoneNumber: phone,
        Interests: interests,
        TellUsWhy: description

    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
})
```

**`partners.html`**

```
<form id="partnerForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-large" id="row1">
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter">
        <label for="prefix">Prefix:</label><br>
        <select class="w3-white" id="prefixes" name="prefix">
        <option value="not-selected"></option>
        <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
        <option value="mrs_and_ms">Mrs. / Ms.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container  w3-quarter">
        <label for="givenName">First Name:</label>
        <input class="w3-white" style="max-width: 100%;" type="text" id="givenName"    name="gname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-quarter">
        <label for="surName">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="w3-white" style="max-width: 100%;" type="text" id="surName" name="sname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-quarter">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
        <input class="w3-white" style="max-width: 100%;" type="text" id="title" name="title">
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="w3-row w3-padding-large" id="row3">
    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-left-align w3-half w3-mobile">
        <h2>Areas of Interest</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" name="interests" value="all">
        <label for="selectAll">All Aspects of C.O.M.E.</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bolPantry" name="interests" value="bolPantry">
        <label for="bolPantry">Bread of Life Pantry</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="FeedMySheep" name="interests" value="FeedMySheep">
        <label for="FeedMySheep">Feed My Sheep</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="GiftedShop" name="interests" value="GiftedShop">
        <label for="GiftedShop">Gifted Shop</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="GoodNews" name="interests" value="GoodNewsGiveaway">
        <label for="GoodNewsGiveaway">Good News Giveaway</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="KingdomsFlock" name="interests" value="KingdomsFlock">
        <label for="KingdomsFlock">Kingdom's Flock</label><br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="OutdoorBazaar" name="interests" value="OutdoorBazaar">
        <label for="OutdoorBazaar">Outdoor Bazaar</label><br>

    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-half w3-mobile">
        <p>Please describe your proposed partnership below.<br>Please include what <em>you and/or your organization</em>
        <br>(are/is) hoping to gain from our partnership,<br> what you are able to contribute, <br> how our missions and goals are aligned, <br> and any other details that will aid in getting to know you.
        </p>

        <textarea class="w3-white w3-col" style="height:200px; align-content:left;" cols="100" id="description" name="tellUsWhy" wrap="hard" required></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input class="w3-btn submit form w3-white w3-border we-border-black w3-round-xxlarge w3-hover-deep-purple" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="firebase.js"></script>
<script src="partnerScripts.js"></script>
```